# How to write a sharing extension for Kindle Paperwhite?

Tags: plugins, share, sharing, kindle, kindle-kdk

I want write a custom sharing plugin for my Kindle Paperwhite. Currently I can share text to twitter but I want to share to pump.io enabled websites. Which SDK, language should I use and how can I install it on my device?

Comment: Curiosity - how to you share text to twitter from your device?

Comment: @csg its supported by default. I can add twitter account in settings and then whenever I long press and select a text I can share it from pop up menu.